# How to determine concrete type in extension?

Tags: swift

I want to extend `Array` to translate arrays into sets, where possible. The following extension does that but in the debugger console, the elements of the set are explicitly labeled `AnyHashable`. Why is this so? But more importantly, is there a way to determine the concrete type of the element (i.e. `String`) in the extension so that it returns a type-matching set?

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    var asSet: Set<AnyHashable> {
        return Set(self)
    }
}

let someArray: [String] = ["kiwi", "mango", "mango"]

print(someArray.asSet) // actual output:  [AnyHashable("kiwi"), AnyHashable("mango")]
                       // desired output: ["kiwi", "mango"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just avoid `AnyHashable`, and return a set of the generic type:

```
var asSet: Set<Element> {
    return Set(self)
}
```

In your example, that will return a `Set<String>`.

Comment: I would name it just `set` considering that there is no casting involved. Btw it would be much more concise to extend `Sequence`. `extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {` `var set: Set<Element> { .init(self) }` `}`